# Apex Charts Barchart Dynamic Data is not working and xaxis is display weird

Tags: angular, bar-chart, apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

the Problem is that i build in the ApexChart Barchart into my Code. It generate the time series Dynamically with X and Y Coordinates for the Axis, but it doesnt display it correctly in the xaxis. I configured the xaxis with the MIN and Max Value (Min = first Day of the Month, Max = last Day of the Month).

Code Description:

I have build in the Barchart into the Code Like this:

```
monthChartOptions: ApexOptions = {
    series: [],
    chart: {
      type: "bar",
      height: 350,
      stacked: true
    },
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        options: {
          legend: {
            position: "bottom",
            offsetX: -10,
            offsetY: 0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    xaxis: {
      min: (new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), 1).getTime()), // first
      max: (new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth() + 1, 0).getTime()), //last
      tickAmount: 6,
      labels: {
        formatter: function (value) {
          return (
            new Date(value).getDate() + "/" + (new Date(value).getMonth() + 1)
          );
        }
      }
    },
    fill: {
      opacity: 1
    },
    legend: {
      offsetX: 50,
    },
    tooltip: {
      shared: true,
      intersect: false,
      y: {
        formatter: function (y) {
          if (typeof y !== "undefined") {
            if (y > 1000) {
              return (y / 1000).toFixed(2) + ' kW';
            } else {
              return y.toFixed(0) + " W";
            }
          }
          return y;
        }
      },
      x: {
        format: "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"
      },
      followCursor: true,
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false,
      enabledOnSeries: [2]
    }
  };
```

I generate the Dataseries like this

x = Timestamp in UNIX,
y = Value

```
{
    "name": "Usage",
    "color": "#ff9f43",
    "data": [
        {
            "x": 1666216800000,
            "y": 36426
        },
        {
            "x": 1666303200000,
            "y": 37068
        },
        {
            "x": 1666389600000,
            "y": 39552
        },
        {
            "x": 1666476000000,
            "y": 5857
        },
        {
            "x": 1666562400000,
            "y": 5469
        },
        {
            "x": 1666821600000,
            "y": 6452
        },
        {
            "x": 1666908000000,
            "y": 37626
        },
        {
            "x": 1666994400000,
            "y": 6268
        },
        {
            "x": 1666476000000,
            "y": 5857
        },
        {
            "x": 1666476000000,
            "y": 5857
        },
        {
            "x": 1666562400000,
            "y": 5469
        },
        {
            "x": 1666562400000,
            "y": 5469
        },
        {
            "x": 1666648800000,
            "y": 6141
        },
        {
            "x": 1666648800000,
            "y": 6141
        },
        {
            "x": 1666476000000,
            "y": 5857
        },
        {
            "x": 1666476000000,
            "y": 5857
        },
        {
            "x": 1666562400000,
            "y": 5469
        },
        {
            "x": 1666562400000,
            "y": 5469
        },
        {
            "x": 1666648800000,
            "y": 6141
        },
        {
            "x": 1666648800000,
            "y": 6141
        },
        {
            "x": 1666735200000,
            "y": 37842
        },
        {
            "x": 1666821600000,
            "y": 6452
        },
        {
            "x": 1666994400000,
            "y": 6268
        },
        {
            "x": 1666994400000,
            "y": 6268
        },
        {
            "x": 1666476000000,
            "y": 5857
        },
        {
            "x": 1666562400000,
            "y": 5469
        },
        {
            "x": 1666648800000,
            "y": 6141
        },
        {
            "x": 1666648800000,
            "y": 6141
        },
        {
            "x": 1666821600000,
            "y": 6452
        },
        {
            "x": 1666821600000,
            "y": 6452
        },
        {
            "x": 1666821600000,
            "y": 6452
        },
        {
            "x": 1666994400000,
            "y": 6268
        },
        {
            "x": 1666994400000,
            "y": 6268
        },
        {
            "x": 1666821600000,
            "y": 6452
        },
        {
            "x": 1666994400000,
            "y": 6268
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the Result of it but the xAxis is not display correctly as i expected, its a weird behavior.

[image]

the Image Below show what i want to Achive

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the type of your `xaxis`. By default, it is `'category'`, not `'datetime'`: [xaxis – ApexCharts.js](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/xaxis/)

Add a single line of code and your snippet works:

```js
let options = {
  series: [{
    name: "Usage",
    color: "#ff9f43",
    data: [
      {
        "x": 1666216800000,
        "y": 36426
      },
      {
        "x": 1666303200000,
        "y": 37068
      },
      {
        "x": 1666389600000,
        "y": 39552
      },
      {
        "x": 1666476000000,
        "y": 5857
      },
      {
        "x": 1666562400000,
        "y": 5469
      },
      {
        "x": 1666821600000,
        "y": 6452
      },
      {
        "x": 1666908000000,
        "y": 37626
      },
      {
        "x": 1666994400000,
        "y": 6268
      },
      {
        "x": 1666476000000,
        "y": 5857
      },
      {
        "x": 1666476000000,
        "y": 5857
      },
      {
        "x": 1666562400000,
        "y": 5469
      },
      {
        "x": 1666562400000,
        "y": 5469
      },
      {
        "x": 1666648800000,
        "y": 6141
      },
      {
        "x": 1666648800000,
        "y": 6141
      },
      {
        "x": 1666476000000,
        "y": 5857
      },
      {
        "x": 1666476000000,
        "y": 5857
      },
      {
        "x": 1666562400000,
        "y": 5469
      },
      {
        "x": 1666562400000,
        "y": 5469
      },
      {
        "x": 1666648800000,
        "y": 6141
      },
      {
        "x": 1666648800000,
        "y": 6141
      },
      {
        "x": 1666735200000,
        "y": 37842
      },
      {
        "x": 1666821600000,
        "y": 6452
      },
      {
        "x": 1666994400000,
        "y": 6268
      },
      {
        "x": 1666994400000,
        "y": 6268
      },
      {
        "x": 1666476000000,
        "y": 5857
      },
      {
        "x": 1666562400000,
        "y": 5469
      },
      {
        "x": 1666648800000,
        "y": 6141
      },
      {
        "x": 1666648800000,
        "y": 6141
      },
      {
        "x": 1666821600000,
        "y": 6452
      },
      {
        "x": 1666821600000,
        "y": 6452
      },
      {
        "x": 1666821600000,
        "y": 6452
      },
      {
        "x": 1666994400000,
        "y": 6268
      },
      {
        "x": 1666994400000,
        "y": 6268
      },
      {
        "x": 1666821600000,
        "y": 6452
      },
      {
        "x": 1666994400000,
        "y": 6268
      }
    ]
  }],
  chart: {
    type: "bar",
    height: 350,
    stacked: true
  },
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      options: {
        legend: {
          position: "bottom",
          offsetX: -10,
          offsetY: 0
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  xaxis: {
    // ==============================
    type: "datetime", // <--- HERE
    // ==============================
    min: new Date(2022, 9, 1).getTime(), // first
    max: new Date(2022, 10, 0).getTime(), // last
    tickAmount: 6,
    labels: {
      formatter: function (value) {
        return (
          new Date(value).getDate() + "/" + (new Date(value).getMonth() + 1)
        );
      }
    }
  },
  fill: {
    opacity: 1
  },
  legend: {
    offsetX: 50,
  },
  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    intersect: false,
    y: {
      formatter: function (y) {
        if (typeof y !== "undefined") {
          if (y > 1000) {
            return (y / 1000).toFixed(2) + " kW";
          } else {
            return y.toFixed(0) + " W";
          }
        }
        return y;
      }
    },
    x: {
      format: "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"
    },
    followCursor: true,
  },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false,
    enabledOnSeries: [2]
  }
};

let chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```